# Create user in keycloak through keycloak admin client returns IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, resteasy, keycloak

I want to create a user through keycloak admin client but I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003720: path param realm has not been provided by the parameter map

Here's my bean for keycloak:

```
@Bean
Keycloak keycloak() {
return KeycloakBuilder
    .builder()
    .serverUrl(localhost:9080/auth)
    .realm(REALM)
    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .username(USERNAME)
    .password(PASSWORD)
    .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
    .build();
}
```

I use this code for calling keycloak:

```
CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = new 
CredentialRepresentation();
credentialRepresentation.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
credentialRepresentation.setValue(password);
UserRepresentation userRepresentation = new UserRepresentation();
userRepresentation.setUsername(username);
userRepresentation.setFirstName(firstName);
userRepresentation.setLastName(lastName);
userRepresentation.setEnabled(true);
userRepresentation.setCredentials(
    Arrays.asList(credentialRepresentation));
keycloak.realm(REALM).users().create(userRepresentation);
```

both keycloak and keycloak admin client are the same version (4.0.0.Final)

My stacktrace looks like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003720: path param realm has not been provided by the parameter map
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.replaceParameter(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.buildString(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:581)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.buildFromValues(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:780)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.build(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:772)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.getUri(ClientWebTarget.java:108)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.createRequest(ClientInvoker.java:124)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
>   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy240.grantToken(Unknown Source)
>   at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:89)
>   at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:69)
>   at org.mycompany.usermanagement.service.KeycloakService.createUserInSSO(KeycloakService.java:45)

and here is my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '4.0.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.1.4.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-client', version: '3.1.4.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.1.4.Final'
```

Comment: `path param realm has not been provided by the parameter map`. Means your request contains "realm" while keycloak api doesn't contain this param. You can check this.

Comment: I think it is quite contrary. It is mandatory to fill 'real' parameter. But the big problem is as you can see I've already provided this parameter

Comment: Have you tried to add protocol (http://) to your serverUrl?

Comment: Do you try to analyze the http request sent to keycloak using some tools, like Wireshark or [TCPMon](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/tcpmon/) ? If the error said you did not pass the path param, you should verify it technically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using Spring Boot?

I have tried your scenario for myself, and works well for me (tested on keycloak 4.0.0 and Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE).

I have done 1 change that the way you create Bean Keycloak (my code is from official [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.html)). Make sure that `realm` is `master` and `client_id` is `admin-cli`.

```
@Bean
Keycloak initKeycloakWithAdminRole() {
    return Keycloak.getInstance(
            "http://localhost:8080/auth",
            "master",
            "admin",
            "admin",
            "admin-cli");
```

#### My code

Service
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtcIh.png)

Controller [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eZnd.png)

Depedencies [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC4lz.png)

Comment: Please make "http://"  part of your response bold. It was an important factor in fixing as @Arkady mentioned.